# jetty 9 websockets onFrame event

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

On older versions of jetty (7 and 8) we had an onFrame (http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocket.OnFrame.html) event for websockets. Is there an equivalent in version 9? They have WebSocketListener (http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/WebSocketListener.html) interface but there is no onFrame method defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use annotated websockets to get access to the websocket frames.

Javadoc:

- [`@OnWebSocketFrame`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/annotations/OnWebSocketFrame.html)
- The [`Frame`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/extensions/Frame.html) interface

Example Socket:

```java
package examples;

import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketFrame;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.extensions.Frame;

@WebSocket
public class AnnotatedFramesSocket
{
    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason)
    {
        System.out.printf("onClose(%d, %s)%n",statusCode,reason);
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session sess)
    {
        System.out.printf("onConnect(%s)%n",sess);
    }

    @OnWebSocketFrame
    public void onFrame(Frame frame)
    {
        System.out.printf("onFrame(%s)%n",frame);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to ask, why do you need access to the post-extension-processed frames?

Comment: it appears I don't need. Somehow I thought this is for pre processed frames.

Comment: @DouaBeri There's no API access to the raw frames from the network, not even on Jetty 7/8.  The Frames you get have been processed through the extension stack by the time they reach the specific WebSocket endpoint.  Note: there will never be that kind of access, the extensions being discussed (notably mux) would make this exceedingly complex.